# Avoid unecessary re-render on Context consumer

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following simple piece of React code:

```js
import React, { useReducer, useContext } from "react";

const AppContext = React.createContext();

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INC":
      return { ...state, count: state.count + 1 };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function IncrementButton() {
  const { appState, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext);
  console.log("IncrementButton", appState);
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "INC" })}>
      Increment
    </button>
  );
}

function ShowState() {
  const { appState } = useContext(AppContext);
  console.log("ShowState", appState);
  return (
    <div>{JSON.stringify(appState)}</div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [appState, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { count: 0 });
  console.log("App", appState);
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ appState, dispatch }}>
      <IncrementButton/>
      <ShowState />
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

[Here's the code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-wind-5r209?file=/src/App.js)

Basically what I do here is I create a React Context to share state between two components. The state is a simple integer counter. When `IncrementButton` is clicked it dispatches an action to alter the shared state (i.e increment the counter). `ShowState` then displays the latest count. Components log when they get rendered just to ease observation.

Now, when I click on `IncrementButton` I kinda expect only `ShowState` gets re-rendered. I expect this log output:

```
// first render should render all components //
App {count: 0}
IncrementButton {count: 0}
ShowState {count: 0}

// button click triggers state change, this time I expect only Show state gets re-rendered //
ShowState {count: 1}
```

but instead, I see this output...

```
// first render should render all components //
App {count: 0}
IncrementButton {count: 0}
ShowState {count: 0}

//  button click triggers state change //
App {count: 1}  // <-  !! why this gets re-rendered? 
IncrementButton {count: 1}   // <-  !! why this gets re-rendered?
ShowState {count: 1}
```

(1) I do not expect `IncrementButton` to be re-rendered too because it does not observe the shared state. and Moreover, (2) `App` is not event the Context consumer, I do not expect it to be re-rendered also.

How can I avoid unnecessary re-render on `IncrementButton`? Why do `App` gets re-rendered here?

I put together this example to strengthen my understanding on the concept of React Context and also to see how far I can get by just by sharing state and reducer using Context. How far I can avoid using 3rd party state management library like Redux.

Comment: Have you tried instead of using an object with count, to just have count as the value?

Comment: I can try that, but could you elaborate what does it have to do with why App and IncrementButton gets re-rendered?